# How to centralize icon inside small bordered element?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to centralize text inside a bordered element?
When I do border at the element, maybe because its content size is reduced, it gets decentralized.

[image: image of the element]

```css
.circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid #00b0ff 1px;
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.button-styling {
  color: #00b0ff;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.outline-h {
  outline: thin;
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 15px;">
  <h3> With border </h1>
    <div class="circle">
      <mat-icon class="button-styling">+</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="max-width: 15px;">
  <h3> Without border </h1>
    <div class="outline-h">
      <mat-icon class="button-styling">+</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the font has a lot of spacing at the top and bottom so it does not center within your given space. There are lots of ways to center this, you can do it with positioning, you can do it with negative margins, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `position: relative; top: -2px; left: 4px;` will fix but there are many ways to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to center the text element:

```css
.circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid #00b0ff 1px;
  color: #00b0ff;
  /*Add*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 15px;">
  <h3>With border</h3>
  <div class="circle">
    <mat-icon class="button-styling">+</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
.circle {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center it using `display: flex`.

Check it's browser support though: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
.circle {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid #00b0ff 1px;
  color: #00b0ff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-styling {
  color: #00b0ff;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.outline-h {
  outline: thin;
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 15px;">
  <h3> With border </h1>
    <div class="circle">
      <mat-icon class="button-styling">+</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="max-width: 15px;">
  <h3> Without border </h1>
    <div class="outline-h">
      <mat-icon class="button-styling">+</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thinking behind this works but as you can see it isn't centered i the circle

Comment: @Huangism It looks centered to me in the snippet.

Comment: I don't know how you can say that is centered, the plus sign is too low in the circle, it's only horizontally centered but not vertically